# Создание вложенных списков в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Мне необходимо создать список в виде древовидной структуры. Что-то вроде:

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <span>Папка 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span>Папка 2</span>
    <ul class="list">
       <li class="item">
         <span>Подпапка 1</span>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
         <span>Подпапка 2</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">Папка 3</li>
</ul>
```

Я создала массив с объектами - каждым элементом списка, элементам, у которых есть вложенность, добавила свойство filling: 'full' и свойство items с массивом из вложенных в этот элемент элементов. Вот так:

```js
const ServicesItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
    text: 'Терапия',
    filling: 'full',
    items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Подпапка 1',
          filling: 'empty',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Подпапка 2',
          filling: 'empty',
        },
    ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    text: 'Хирургия',
    filling: 'empty',
    },
 ]
```

Список первого уровня выводит компонент:

```js
class ServicesList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const servicesListTemplate = this.props.data.map(function (item, index) {
            return (
                <li className="services-list__item" key={index}>
         <div className={`services-list__item-title-group services-list__item-title-group--${item.filling}`}>
        <a href="" className="services-list__item-title">{item.text}</a>
      </div>
                </li>
            )
        })

        return (
            <ul className="services-list ">
                {servicesListTemplate}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Однако не совсем понимаю, как теперь добавить условие, что при наличии свойства item.filling=="full" внутрь li вставляется еще один такой же компонент с элементами уже из массива item.items. При этом вложенность не должна ограничиваться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести данные в react в несколько строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947126/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-react-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в итоге получилось так:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Папка 1",
    values: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Подпапка 1",
        values: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Подпапка 2"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Подпапка 3",
            values: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Папка 2",
        values: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

function ListItem({ item }) {
  let children = null;
  if (item.values && item.values.length) {
    children = (
      <ul>
        {item.values.map(i => (
          <ListItem item={i} key={i.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  return (
    <li>
      {item.name}
      {children}
    </li>
  );
}

function App() {
  
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```